# Loopback where filter geo near query [error: unable to find index for $geoNear query]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm trying to get a count of users(Cronies) within a radius. I'm using mongodb + loopback and can successfully query by location with a remote method.

Yet, when I try to supply nearby in the where parameter through the api explorer I get an error as follows:

parameter provided as "where":

```
        {"last_location": {"near": [-33.8670522,151.1957362]}, "maxDistance":1}
```

Request URL:

`http://localhost:3000/api/Cronies/count?where=%7B%22last_location%22%3A%20%7B%22near%22%3A%20%5B-33.8670522%2C151.1957362%5D%7D%2C%20%22maxDistance%22%3A1%7D&access_token=AYlOjRtu77JWNywHVMtRqEAZfLzKNyq2OFV31ZKHaUSQBNZojxSJb9Q5QI7RjAXc`

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "MongoError",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "error processing query: ns=fresh.Crony limit=0 skip=0\nTree: $and\n    maxDistance == 1\n    GEONEAR  field=last_location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query",
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "error processing query: ns=fresh.Crony limit=0 skip=0\nTree: $and\n    maxDistance == 1\n    GEONEAR  field=last_location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query",
    "code": 2,
    "stack": "MongoError: error processing query: ns=fresh.Crony limit=0 skip=0\nTree: $and\n    maxDistance == 1\n    GEONEAR  field=last_location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query\n    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/alex/dev/crony/crony-backend/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)\n    at /Users/alex/dev/crony/crony-backend/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:754:66\n    at /Users/alex/dev/crony/crony-backend/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/context.js:74:17\n    at bound (domain.js:250:14)\n    at runBound (domain.js:263:12)\n    at Callbacks.emit (/Users/alex/dev/crony/crony-backend/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)\n    at null.messageHandler (/Users/alex/dev/crony/crony-backend/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:243:23)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/alex/dev/crony/crony-backend/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)\n    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't generate the index column, it's simple, just connect at your `mongo shell` and use:

```
db.<collection>.ensureIndex({point:"2dsphere"})
```

Source: Look [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188875/mongodb-unable-to-find-index-for-geonear-query)

I had the same problem and that answer work for me.

Comment: Make sure that if the geolocation field in your collection is not called `point`, that you change the above index generation call to match it. Also, if `2dsphere` doesn't work for you, try `2d` index type.