# Geospatial query not working ONLY in Ubuntu with NodeJS and Mongoose, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose, geometry

I have a NodeJS server Mongodb, Express and Mongoose. I am doing a geospatial query. I am running locally on Mac and everything works fine. When I FTP my ENTIRE project into the Ubuntu box, I can run the project but the queries fail:

```
    { name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'error processing query: ns=crime.crimesTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=0.000156961 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
  waitedMS: 0,
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'error processing query: ns=crime.crimesTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=0.000156961 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
  code: 2 }
GET /crimeindex?lat=41.8841661&lon=-87.6411432 500 86.505 ms - 453
```

I should mention that SAVING to the database works as expected

Comment: It looks like this may be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188875/mongodb-unable-to-find-index-for-geonear-query ...are you on the right collection?

Comment: @S.McGraw Thanks a lot! Problem solved

Comment: Sure thing! Happy to help!