# How can i save a ParseGeoPoint Object in mongodb (using mLab)

Tags: mongodb, parse-server, geopoints, mlab

> I want to save address ( a relational object ) with geopoints, so as to
>   later retrieve all Events which have address near to provided
>   location, it will be all based on coordinates. Using following piece
>   of code -

```
$address = new ParseObject("Address");
$point = new ParseGeoPoint(23.80, -120.90);
$address->set("location", $point);
$address->save();
```

> Type of location in my db is geopoint, but it gives me continuous
>   error-

**Internal Server Error . Error code :exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't serialize an unsaved Parse.Object'**

Post this I tried following code -

```
$address = new ParseObject("Address");
$address->save();
$point = new ParseGeoPoint(23.80, -120.90);
$address->set("location", $point);
$address->save();
```

> I tried this, so as to remove above error of unsaved Parse.Object, but
>   it ended up saving only my address object and never saving location in
>   it.  How can I achieve this?

Full code view -

```
function saveEvent() {
   $title = $this->input->post('title');
   $eventCode = $this->input->post('eventCode');
   $event = new ParseObject("Event");
   $event->set("title", $title);
   $event->set("eventCode", $eventCode);
   $address = $this->saveAddressObject($event, $url);
   $event_address_Relation = $event->getRelation("address");
   if (!empty($address)) {
            $event_address_Relation->add($address);
   }
   $event->save();
  }
function saveAddressObject($event, $url) {
    $fullAddress = $this->input->post('fullAddress');
    $address1 = $this->input->post('address1');
    $address2 = $this->input->post('address2');
    $city = $this->input->post('city');
    $state = $this->input->post('state');
    $zipCode = (int) $this->input->post('zipCode');
    $country = $this->input->post('country');
    $latitude = $this->input->post('latitude');
    $longitude = $this->input->post('longitude');
    try {
            $address = new ParseObject("Address");
            $address->set("fullAddress", $fullAddress);
            $address->set("address1", $address1);
            $address->set("address2", $address2);
            $address->set("city", $city);
            $address->set("state", $state);
            $address->set("zipCode", $zipCode);
            $address->set("country", $country);
            $address->set("latitude", $latitude);
            $address->set("longitude", $longitude);
            $point = new ParseGeoPoint($latitude, $longitude);
            $address->set("location", $point);
            $address->save();
           return $address;
    } catch (ParseException $error) {
        print_r($error);
    } catch (Exception $ex1) {
        print_r($ex1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second example, only one instance of an object can be saved at a time, and the second+ attempts while another attempt is in progress fail silently. At least on iOS. I would imagine it's similar here.

Is this your exact code? The first error you mentioned tends to happen when you try to attach a new object that hasn't been saved yet to another object, and you mentioned that these addresses are used relationally. My bet is that you're trying to attach an object to another as a pointer, and haven't saved the object, which means it does not yet have an ID so you can't create a pointer to it.

Edit - I'm not sure which SDK you're using, but save calls are asynchronous, meaning it doesn't happen right away, so possibly you think you're saving an object first, but really the save hasn't finished, and you then try to attach it to another object? This could also be related to why your second example fails, since you don't have any completion handler that returns after the second save. Perhaps the first one manages to finish, but the second one never does before your function returns.

Comment: So, here 2 objects are involved, first is Event and other is Address ( it is an event's address, and so relational ). Here is what I m doing (as per first example - 1)Saving Event Object 2)Saving Address Object 3)Saving addressRelation to Event Object. In the 2) step I m attaching Geopoints before saving Address Object. And I m using parse-php-sdk.

Comment: The first example is only showing you saving the address object, and nothing about that code looks off. If you could update to your actual code, it would be easier to see exactly what's going on. I would bet that the issue comes from step 3), as the other two saves likely haven't gone through in the background, due to the asynchronasity mentioned in my edit.

Comment: What language are you working with here? And where is this code? I'm unfamiliar with some of the syntax. and don't know how the platform you're using handles asynchronous calls.

Comment: Though it looks like the issue is setting up the relation on the Event before the event is saved. Relations use pointers, and the event has no object id yet.

Comment: It is parse-php-sdk, and the address relation actually gets save in the event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152659/discussion-between-urvashi-and-jake-t).