# Planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, 2dsphere

I am using `$nearSphere` operator in my query and passing the **latitude and longitude** but it returns

> > **error- unable to find the index for $geoNear query**.

- I found a couple of solutions and I have used in the schema:

  `scheduleRideSchema.index({ source: '2dsphere' });`
- I am using  **mongoose**.

  `source: {
              $nearSphere: {
                  $geometry: {
                      type: "Point",
                      coordinates: sourceCord.coordinates
                  },
                  $maxDistance: 4000
              }
          }`

  > > Error: planner returned error: unable to find the index for `$geoNear` query'

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23189240/598812

Comment: unfortunately, this is also not working!

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput  Did you ask that question? Solution works

Comment: I'm also getting same issue actually.

Comment: Try running the query directly through Mongo shell and not Mongoose. Lets first clear issue is DB side or Mongoose. I'm suspecting value of sourceCord.coordinates is causing some issue.

Comment: But after sometime this gives the successful response using the same coordinates ..@RajatGoel

Comment: But this solution is not working for me. And I have asked the question @Ashh